# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 (runs at web but doesn't at emulator)

Tags: flutter, gradle, exception

I'm having this issue when I try to run the standard flutter new project app:

```c
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\AndroidStudioProjects\good_heart\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.5. Current version is 4.10.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in E:\AndroidStudioProjects\good_heart\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-6.5-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This happens when I try to run it in a android emulator (one provided by android studio), doesn't happen when I run it in Edge(web) though, it runs smoothly.

Any thoughts? Already tried installing older versions of JDK (such as 11 and 8). Reinstalling Android Studio and flutter... Running it from VScode outputs the same error.

Comment: run `flutter doctor` and show us some results

Comment: everything checks out in the ```c flutter doctor```

Answer (score 0):

If you Use Android Studio Emulator

Open **AVD Manager** then select your Emulator right click it and select or click on **Wipe data** or **Cold Boot Now** and then run or launch your app your project

hope its help to you

Comment: yes, using the command flutter doctor told me to.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your Gradle wrapper
go to android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and change the last line to: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip Android Studio will download the necessary library.

Comment: Did it and the problem persists... (to be honest this was already the last line of my android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file, even though I copied and pasted the one you posted and nothing changed, same error)

Comment: try to change it to gradle-6.5-all.zip or gradle-7.2-all.zip

Comment: can you share  android\app\build.gradle file

Comment: ```c
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

Its not formatting for some reason, my file has breaklines.