# Flutter App Rejected for External Storage Request for Android API level 30 and above. Below is the code:

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

My app needs storage permission to access and pick pdf files on the device storage. For Android API level 30 I used   and wrote the code as below:

```
 Future<void> askPermission() async {
    if (androidInfo != null) {
      if (androidInfo!.version.sdkInt! >= 30 && Platform.isAndroid) {
        await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
      } else if (androidInfo!.version.sdkInt! < 30 && Platform.isAndroid) {
        await Permission.storage.request();
      }
    }
  }


FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['pdf'],
    );

In android manifest:
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

But the App was rejected saying:
Issue: Access to device storage not required

The feature you identified does not require unrestricted access to device storage. There are other privacy friendly options for accessing files in shared storage, such as using the system file picker, or, depending on the use case, you can follow the recommendations for receiving data from other apps listed here.

Please update your app so that the feature uses a privacy friendly alternative and remove All Files Access (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission...

What changes should I make for the app to be compliant and access storage for Android API level 30. User needs to pick PDF files from Storage and after the task completes new PDF files will be saved in the Storage.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561737/getting-permission-to-the-external-storage-file-provider-plugin

Comment: try this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68911129/13997210) hope it helps to you

Comment: Did you see the example app from file_picker creator? They don't have any such permissions

Comment: All I can see is `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is needed for the plugin to function correctly and just do that

Comment: @stacktrace234 That link you provided is related to Android version 10..my query is about Android 11 which restricts access to storage-  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> to be added for Android 11 but we have to provide reasons for accessing as per the policy

Comment: @Ravindra That answer is not related to the question..thanks

Comment: how did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the Android Manifest you have to define upto which sdk you want to request permission

Replace

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

with

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>
```