# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' Flutter 2.2.0

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have been facing this issue after I reset the Android Emulator as it got hanged while development so I just wiped the data. And since then I am facing this issue only for this specific project while for other projects they are working fine.

#### Error Logs

```
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling
software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\flutter2\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\flutter2\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. 
Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         9.9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

#### Flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1165], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.2.0 at D:\flutter2
    • Framework revision b22742018b (4 months ago), 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
    • Engine revision a9d88a4d18
    • Dart version 2.13.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.59.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.25.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.159
    • Edge (web)              • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 92.0.902.78

• No issues found!
```

#### pubspec.yaml

```yaml
name: donation_app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  # other packages
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0
  syncfusion_flutter_sliders: ^19.2.55
  charts_flutter: ^0.11.0
  carousel_slider: ^3.0.0
  bottom_navy_bar: ^6.0.0  
  share: ^2.0.4
  screenshot: ^1.2.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  permission_handler: ^8.1.4+1
  image_picker: ^0.7.5+3
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^2.0.0
  
  # analytics
  amplitude_flutter: ^3.2.1

  # firebase
  firebase_auth: ^3.0.1
  firebase_core: ^1.4.0
  firebase_storage: ^10.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0

  # local storage
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6

  # encryption
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.0

  # stripe
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.8
  dio: ^4.0.0  
  js: ^0.6.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/events/
    - assets/logo/
    - assets/orgs/
    - .env
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Comfortaa
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Comfortaa-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Comfortaa-Medium.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Comfortaa-Light.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Comfortaa-Bold.ttf
          weight: 900
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

### Solution Tried

- Reinstalling `flutter`
- Tried clearing the packages & getting them again

`flutter clean`

`flutter pub get`

- Tried deleting `pubspec.lock` and running `flutter pub get`
- Removing `rm android/settings.gradle` and running `flutter create .`
- Tried removing `C:/USERNAME/.gradle` and `C:/USERNAME/.gradle/caches` both
- Tried upgrading Android Studio
- Tried upgrading flutter to `flutter 2.2.3` the latest version!
- Tried replacing `settings.gradle` code with the below one:

```
include ':app' 

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
   pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
   def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
   include ":$name"
   project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

**And please let me know if you need anything else for better understanding :)**

Comment: try this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68911129/13997210) hope it helps you

Comment: `./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace` Try to get the stacktrace, it might get more clear what's troubling Flutter

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Nope, didn't work

Comment: @gtxtreme "." is not recognized as command. Could you tell me how to get it?

Comment: You're on Windows I'm assuming?

Comment: Yes, I'm using windows

Answer (score 1):

If you're using outdated plugins and recently ran `flutter upgrade`, it's possible that cache of outdated packages is still kept and causing the issue. What you can try doing here is run `flutter pub get` and `flutter pub upgrade` if outdated versions were displayed on the logs. Running `flutter pub outdated` to upgrade the package versions should also work.