# flutter error at my first project build.gradle

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\lenovo\StudioProjects\untitled\android\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\lenovo\StudioProjects\untitled\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\lenovo.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\8o7x4j6rhvqslglhwver2v6gy).
> > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68911129/13997210) answer hope it helps you

Comment: Try this Clean your build rebuild your Gradle wipeout or uninstall the previous install app from the emulator and then install app