# Flutter Run Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.Could not find com.android.tools.build: :4.1.0

Tags: flutter

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build: :4.1.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/ /4.1.0/ -4.1.0.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/ /4.1.0/ -4.1.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68911129/13997210)

Comment: Can you try updating the build-tools in `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Ok. let me try updating the build-tools

Answer (score 0):

If you are Mac User

Set JAVA_HOME path using  applying this command.

after that type below command in terminal:

cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre

ln -s ../jre jdk

ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk

Then again Open terminal and check with this commad

flutter doctor -v

This solve my issues